# How can I reprogram keys of one of my keyboards?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Not sure if this is a question for this forum but:

I have a laptop and a connected keyboard (where some keys are not working properly). I would like to edit the keys so that all keys on the left side (does not mater where exactly) would do one thing like typing equating to the key "Enter" and the other half would be "Space". **I would still like to use my regular laptop keayboard as normal** though. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Truly, keyboards are inexpensive.  Just replace it with a good keyboard.

Comment: @John, thanks for the suggestion. I got several keyboards already. I am thinking doing a project with the one not working properly.